# Obtener la totalidad de campos de un documento

Tags: android, firebase

Cómo puedo obtener la totalidad de campos de un documento de Firestore.
Por ejemplo si en una colección tengo varios documentos, y en cada documento tengo campos; pero cada uno de estos documentos no tiene la misma cantidad de campos, algunos tienen mas y otros menos, incluso dichos campos son distintos en cada documento.
Estoy intentando obtener dichos campos en una lista pero no puedo usar getString(),ya que no se qué campos tienen un documento en determinado momento.

```
fsdbData.collection("class")
            .orderBy("nom")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.d("Ex", "Excepcion", e);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (queryDocumentSnapshots.size() != 0) {
                        lisClases.clear();
                        adaClases.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        doc.
                        lisClases.add(new ItemClase(
                                doc.getString("nom"),

                        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

El método `getData` de un `DocumentSnapshot` te regresa un `Map`, puedes obtener la lista de campos de ahí con `keySet`.